# Assign WordPress current username value in a var in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm using livewebinar embed code and i'm try to pass the Current WordPress user name in Embed Javascript

Here is the code

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

var _options = {
    '_license_key':'***-***-***',
    '_role_token':'',
    '_registration_token':'',
    '_widget_containerID':'embedWidget',
    '_widget_width':'100%',
    '_widget_height':'100vh',
    '_widget_nickname': I NEED TO PASS THE CURRENT WPUSER IN THIS PARAMETER, <<<<<<<-----------

}; .............. <script>
```

The goal is Get the Current Wordpress user name value and pass it inside _nickname parameter

Comment: you alternatively use `wp_get_current_user()->display_name` or something like that. but are you sure you want to initialize it in JS? your license key is going to be exposed that way

Answer (score 0):

thats how you can get wp current user details

```
 $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
   
    echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . '<br />';
    echo 'User email: ' . $current_user->user_email . '<br />';
    echo 'User first name: ' . $current_user->user_firstname . '<br />';
    echo 'User last name: ' . $current_user->user_lastname . '<br />';
    echo 'User display name: ' . $current_user->display_name . '<br />';
    echo 'User ID: ' . $current_user->ID . '<br />';
```